# Gmail SPF records from server don't apply correctly

Tags: dns, gmail, spf

I'm running my domain on two servers (**primary** server and **blog** server) and I manage my mails with Google Apps for business (MX records correctly set).

However, I want to send emails from both servers (**primary** is a send-only EXIM4 server) and they should not be marked as spam. Therefore I want to set a correct SPF record, but Google keeps telling me that `spf=neutral` instead of `spf=positive`.

My current SPF records looks as follows:

`v=spf1 ip4:<blog IP> ip4:<primary IP> include:_spf.google.com ~all`

What do I have to change in order to get my mails through spam detection?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

The record was okay, but I had to create a **TXT** record with the content above. Not a **SPF** record, which is weird. But so is technology.